# Cannot call 'operator >' with 'expr1'=series[bool]. The argument should be of type: float

Tags: tradingview-api

I am trying to do the following. I am trying to compare 3 EMAs and but it is giving me this error msg. What can i do so I can compare the EMAs? I am not good at coding to be honest, Any help?

```
RSI50 = rsi(close, 1000)
RSI25 = rsi(close, 25)
RSI100 = rsi(close, 100)

Long = RSI25 > RSI100 > RSI50
Short = RSI25 < RSI100 < RSI50



strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, 100.0, when = Long)
strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short, 100.0, when = Short)
```